# Extract Substring from String / Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the datas from a variable called "apps".

And I have this datastructure:

```
{"id"=>001,
 "name"=>"test01",
 "users"=>
 [{"id"=>01,
   "name"=>"test02"},
  {"id"=>02,
   "name"=>"test03"}]}
```

How can I extract the namevalues from the users substring?

I have tried

```
apps.each do |test|
  data = Hash.new
  data['id'] = test['id']
  data['name'] = test['name']
  data['username'] = test['users.name']
  userdata = data
  userdata.each do |row|
    File.write('test.yaml', row.to_yaml)
  end
end
```

But that doesn't work.

desired output would be:

> {"id"=>"01", "name"=>"test02","id"=>"02", "name"=>"test03"}

Comment: Please include an example of your desired output

Comment: Is your `apps` variable a hash or an array of hashes?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts it is an array of hashes.

Comment: `{"id"=>"01", "name"=>"test02","id"=>"02", "name"=>"test03"}` hash keys must be unique, so this is not possible. You can have `{"id" => ["01","02"],  "name" => ["test02", "test03"] }` though

Answer (score 0):

you just need to `require 'yaml'` in order to use it on Hash/Array classes, you don't need to iterate over array or hash, `to_yaml` already handles this for you.

```rb
require 'yaml'

data = {"id"=>001,
 "name"=>"test01",
 "users"=>
 [{"id"=>01,
   "name"=>"test02"},
  {"id"=>02,
   "name"=>"test03"}]}

File.write('test.yml', data["users"].to_yaml)
```